# Any quick and dirty anti-aliasing techniques for a rotated UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage, antialiasing

I've got a UIImageView (full frame and rectangular) that i'm rotating with a CGAffineTransform. The UIImage of the UIImageView fills the entire frame. When the image is rotated and drawn the edges appear noticeably jagged. Is there anything I can do to make it look better? It's clearly not being anti-aliased with the background.

Comment: Is the image being internally anti-aliased -- is it just the edges that are jagged or the whole thing?

BTW I would recommend using a CALayer if possible.

Comment: It's for the iPhone so I believe it's already CALayer backed.

Comment: Indeed, but why carry all the UIView/UIResponder baggage if you don't need to?

Comment: well, in my case they need to views need to register touches

Comment: and only the edges are jagged... image itself is anti-aliasing just fine.

Comment: Check out Johan Kool's answer... very simple, and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember to set the appropriate anti-alias options:

```
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(theContext, true);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(theContext, true);
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference when adding these Antialiasing lines to enclosing the UIImageView's drawRect...as well as the enclosing superview's. Even tried: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh); to no avail... When the UIImageView rect gets transformed (rotated) the edges are always jaggy..

Comment: Best way to solve that problem is by adding a 1px transparent border to your image prior to rotation.

Comment: How would you add the transparent border?  I'm have the same issue while rotating a CALayer with perspective.

Comment: Could someone provide a tip on this 1px transparent border trick? I've set a UIView's layer.borderColor and layer.borderWidth, but it does not fix it for me.

Comment: My image was coming via glReadPixels (OpenGL ES frame buffer capture) so I was able to set alpha on the RGBA memory buffer directly. For those also in this situation make sure you don't use premultiplied in your CGImageCreate call (ie I supplied kCGImageAlphaLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big for CGBitmapInfo).

Comment: Explanation why the 1px transparent pixel fixes the problem: the jagged line is the edge of the polygon that Cocoa draws there and since your texture has colors to the edge it can't be anti-aliased. The image inside the edges is anti-aliased though.

Comment: This is besides the problem. The problem is in CALayer space, and not CGContext drawing space.

Comment: Okay, and how to use it. Or is it for drawing code only?

Answer (score 55):

The edges of CoreAnimation layers aren't antialiased by default on iOS. However, there is a key that you can set in Info.plist that enables antialiasing of the edges: UIViewEdgeAntialiasing.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

If you don't want the performance overhead of enabling this option, a work-around is to [add a 1px transparent border around the edge of the image](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/). This means that the 'edges' of the image are no longer on the edge, so don't need special treatment!

Comment: This is super sweet! So simple, and yet, so powerful! :D

Comment: crazy that this isn't the top answer

Comment: Any hint on what is the impact on the efficiency?

Comment: @MathieuGodart Not tested myself, as it functioned well enough for me where I needed it. Use Instruments to figure out how much it impacts performance for you. Of course, Apple turns this off by default for a reason.

Comment: I noticed that setting UIViewEdgeAntialiasing to YES in the Info.plist file is messing with all `UIAlertView`'s corners.

Answer (score 28):

**New API – iOS 6/7**

*Also works for iOS 6, as noted by @Chris, but wasn't made public until iOS 7.*

Since iOS 7, CALayer has a new property `allowsEdgeAntialiasing` which does exactly what you want in this case, without incurring the overhead of enabling it for all views in your application! This is a property of CALayer, so to enable this for a UIView you use  `myView.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = YES`.

Comment: This is a great API.  Note that it also works on iOS 6 (though apparently was only added/enabled in the iOS 7 SDK).

Comment: This is probably a best question to solve this issue

Answer (score 17):

just add 1px transparent border to your image

```
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageRect.size, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(1,1,image.size.width-2,image.size.height-2)];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: works great here too.   fyi:  simpler inset calc: CGRectInset(imageRect, 1.0, 1.0)

Answer (score 6):

just add "Renders with edge antialiasing" with YES in plist and it will work.

Answer (score 5):

I would totally recommend the following library.

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

It contains lots of useful extensions to UIImage that solve this problem and also include code for generating thumbnails etc.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've found to have smooth edges and a sharp image is to do this:

```
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.photo.image.size.width, self.photo.image.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageRect.size, NO, 0.0);
[self.photo.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(1, 1, self.photo.image.size.width - 2, self.photo.image.size.height - 2)];
self.photo.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Adding the Info.plist key like some people describe has a big hit on performance and if you use that then you're basically applying it to everything instead of just the one place you need it.

Also, don't just use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageRect.size);` otherwise the layer will be blurry.  You have to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` like I've shown.

Comment: This is a great point regarding **UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions** .. usually you have to set the **opaque option to NO**. I was drawing lines (ie, lines on a transparent bg), and then using renderInContext to draw the image of the lines, into, an existing photo. **Of course, it's critical to use opaque "NO".** So, this was very obvious to me - after iWasRobbed told me about it  :)  Thanks, robbed!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution from [here](https://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/efficient-edge-antialiasing/), and it's perfect:

```
+ (UIImage *)renderImageFromView:(UIView *)view withRect:(CGRect)frame transparentInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets {
    CGSize imageSizeWithBorder = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width + insets.left + insets.right, frame.size.height + insets.top + insets.bottom);
    // Create a new context of the desired size to render the image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSizeWithBorder, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Clip the context to the portion of the view we will draw
    CGContextClipToRect(context, (CGRect){{insets.left, insets.top}, frame.size});
    // Translate it, to the desired position
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -frame.origin.x + insets.left, -frame.origin.y + insets.top);

    // Render the view as image
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    // Fetch the image
    UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Cleanup
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return renderedImage;
}
```

usage:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage renderImageFromView:view withRect:view.bounds transparentInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```