# How to do antialiasing on a rotated view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any quick and dirty anti-aliasing techniques for a rotated UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136110/any-quick-and-dirty-anti-aliasing-techniques-for-a-rotated-uiimageview)

when a UIView is rotated, it's borders look incredible ugly. There's no antialiasing happening  at all. Also if it's a UIImageView, no antialiasing happens when rotating the transform matrix. Is there a way to achieve smooth edges and smooth rotation of images?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a UIImageView, add a one-pixel transparent border around the image. This will cause the edges of your image to be on the "inside", and because the inside pixels are interpolated when rotating, the borders will magically become antialiased. This also works for rotating UIButtons that have a custom image.

Comment: For the longest time, I searched for a way to “add a one-pixel transparent border” around my UIImageView. I tried enlarging the `.frame` by 2 `CGFloat` s and varoious other methods until I figured you probably meant: add the border to the loaded UIImage (in my case constructed from a PNG file).

Comment: no I reckon he means set borderWidth on the view.layar (needs QuartzCore import) - see this post for more details: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Comment: Either way will work. You can add the border statically to the image itself, or add it dynamically to the UIImage at runtime, as described in my blog post.

Comment: Worked for me. You are my hero of the day.