# iPhone - Jagged Edges when applying perspective to CALayer

Tags: iphone, uikit, core-animation, core-graphics, calayer

I have a CALayer that I apply a perspective to using a `CGTransform3D` and specifying the `m14` property.  When the perspective is applied, the layer has jagged edges.  I've heard people mention that adding a 1px transparent border around the layer will help with this.  I don't know how to do that.  I have tried using the `border` and `borderWidth` properties of a CALayer but the jagged edges are still there.  I also tried to reduce the rect that is drawn by 1px on all sides, but it doesn't help either.

Any help would be great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "I've heard people mention," I assume you mean the discussion on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136110/any-quick-and-dirty-anti-aliasing-techniques-for-a-rotated-uiimageview).  What was suggested there was to actually draw the content in your CALayer so that it has a one-pixel transparent border outside of the core content, using the code

```
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(theContext, true);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(theContext, true);
```

within your Quartz drawing for that layer.

There's also the `edgeAntialiasingMask` property on CALayer, but I've seen no impact when using code like the following:

```
layer.edgeAntialiasingMask = kCALayerLeftEdge | kCALayerRightEdge | kCALayerBottomEdge | kCALayerTopEdge;
```

on the antialiasing of transformed layer edges.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465645/how-to-anti-alias-layers-in-iphoneos) for discussion of this, as well as how they solved their problem using one-pixel transparent borders around their images.

Answer (score 11):

The best solution I found for this issue was to set shouldRasterize to YES and set the rasterization scale to the scale of the device's screen.

```
myLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;
myLayer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale // iOS
myLayer.rasterizationScale = NSScreen.mainScreen()!.backingScaleFactor // OSX
```

That will in turn smooth out the edges for you.

Answer (score 1):

Give your CALayer a mask that's inset 0.5 px from each edge:

```
UIView *aliasedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];

CALayer *maskLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, width-1, height-1);
maskLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

aliasedView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

A one pixel border smooths the edges of the content (!) of a layer:

```
- (UIImage *)drawAntiAliased:(UIImage *)image
{
    const int B = 1; // Border width (anti-aliasing)

    // Size of the output image
    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width + 2 * B, image.size.height + 2 * B);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, 0);

    // Draw image with edge anti-aliasing
    [image drawInRect:(CGRect){B, B, image.size}];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

If you want to use the border properties of the layer, this does no longer work, because the border is not part of the contents of the layer and is not affected by the smoothing.

Setting `shouldRasterize` on the other hand affects both the content and the borders.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0:

```
context.setAllowsAntialiasing(true)
context.setShouldAntialias(true)
```