# CGLayer and Anti-aliased CGPaths

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ipad, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I am drawing several `CGPaths` in a Cocoa view in the drawRect method on an iPad.  I started out drawing them straight to the `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` context, but performance went south when my paths got really long. Based on [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701783/iphone-jagged-edges-when-applying-perspective-to-calayer) other questions, I started looking into using `CGLayer`s.

So what I do now is to render a path inside of the `CGContextRef` I get from calling `CGLayerGetContext`. Here's the basic outline of what I'm doing:

```c
// rect comes from the drawRect: method
layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, rect.size, NULL);
layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(layer);
CGContextSetLineCap(layerContext, kCGLineCapRound);

// Set the line styles
CGContextSetLineJoin(layerContext, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(layerContext, 1.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(layerContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

// Create a mutable path
path = CGPathCreateMutable();

// Move to start point
//...

for (int i = 0; i < points.count; i++) {
    // compute controlPoint and anchorPoint
    //...

    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path,
                              nil,
                              controlPoint.x,
                              controlPoint.y,
                              anchorPoint.x,
                              anchorPoint.y);
}
// Stroke the path
CGContextAddPath(layerContext, path);
CGContextStrokePath(layerContext);

// Add the layer to the main context
CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context, CGPointZero, layer);
```

Now, I get good performance drawing, but my lines are extremely jagged and do not seem to be anti-aliased. I've tried adding

```c
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(layerContext, YES);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(layerContext, YES);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(layerContext, kCGInterpolationHigh);
```

to the code above to no avail. I've even set the anti-aliasing properties on the main `context`, with no change. I took screen shots of the same code results, but with the second image being the image created from drawing in the `CGLayer`. As you can see, it is really jagged, despite being the same code, just drawing into a `layerContext`. How can I get the lines in the `CGLayer` to be smooth?

[image: smooth lines]
[image: jagged lines]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason the second image is not anti-aliased is because there was nothing to anti-alias against. The background was empty, and so anti-aliasing didn't work. If you make a big rectangle over the bounds of the view that is entirely transparent, the line will draw with anti-aliasing. However, performance is killed. Better not to go this route.

Comment: Hi @Streeter, I am also stuck with CgLayer isssue, and not able to figure how to draw to CgLayer, I have posted a question regarding this, can you please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341763/how-to-use-cglayer-for-optimal-drawing