# Render CALayer on GPU

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext, cashapelayer

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715749/performance-when-frequently-drawing-cgpaths) by ldoogy, setting the `drawsAsynchronously` property of `CALayer` to true enables a Metal based renderer vastly improving performance.

This [webpage](https://blog.rectorsquid.com/getting-gpu-acceleration-with-nsgraphicscontext/) affirms Idoogy's claim.

However, I do not see any performance difference when `drawsAsynchronously` is set to true or false.

```
let layer = CALayer()
let drawsAsynchronously = true //Makes no difference set to true or false
shapeLayer.drawsAsynchronously = drawsAsynchronously

let f = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1024.0, height: 1024.0)
let cgColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor

var lines: [CGPath] // populated with several hundred paths, some with hundreds of points

let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    
for path in lines {
    let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    pathLayer.path = path
    pathLayer.strokeColor = cgColor
    pathLayer.fillColor = nil
    pathLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    pathLayer.drawsAsynchronously = drawsAsynchronously
    layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(f.size)
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
layer.render(in: ctx!)
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

//time: 0.05170309543609619
print("time: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start)")
```

Idoogy specifies `renderInContext` which is what I am using above. `render(in:)` has replaced `renderInContext` with modern Swift.

Surprisingly, `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` is much slower (nearly 300%), but also makes no difference if `drawsAsynchronously` is set to true or false:

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: f.size)
let capturedImage = renderer.image { (ctx) in
    return layer.render(in: ctx.cgContext)
}

// time: 0.13654804229736328    
print("time: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start)")
```

Is there something I've missed to enable hardware accelerated rendering with `drawsAsynchronously` enabled?

EDIT:

I tried using drawRect method too, since Idoogy mentions `ContextStrokePath`, but it was the slowest yet, and made no difference if `drawsAsynchronously` is enabled or not.

```
class LineView: UIView {
    var lines: [CGPath] //populated with several hundred paths, some with hundreds of points

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let color = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            for path in lines {
                context.saveGState()
                context.addPath(path)
                context.setStrokeColor(color)
                context.setLineWidth(1.0)
                context.strokePath()
                context.restoreGState()
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let drawsAsynchronously = true //Makes no difference set to true or false
            view.layer.drawsAsynchronously = drawsAsynchronously
            let f = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1024.0, height: 1024.0)
            let lineView = LineView(frame: f)
            lineView.layer.drawsAsynchronously = drawsAsynchronously
            view.addSubview(lineView)
            let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(f.size)
            let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            lineView.layer.render(in: ctx!)
            let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            //time: 0.14092397689819336
            print("time: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start)")
         }
```

Since it is so much slower than using `CAShapeLayer` (3x slower), I suspect that maybe using `CAShapeLayer` is using the GPU for rendering to image. I'd still like to get the method described by Idoogy working as none of the 3 methods I've tried show any difference using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to talk about...

First, the speed difference you observed between `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` and `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` is due to the fact that you are rendering different size images.

Assuming you are on a `@3x` device, `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` is rendering a **1024 x 1024** `UIImage`, but its `.scale` is **3**, so it's actually a   **3072 x 3072** ***pixel*** image.

To get equivalent images, change that code block to this:

```
    let fmt = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
    fmt.scale = 1
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: f.size, format: fmt)
    let capturedImage = renderer.image { (ctx) in
        return layer.render(in: ctx.cgContext)
    }
```

now `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` will produce the same **1024 x 1024** pixel image as `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`.

---

Next, you're timing blocks of code which are not directly related to `layer.drawsAsynchronously` -- creating and adding sublayers, generating objects, etc.

Apple's docs on this are not what I would call "in-depth" -- but [Improving Animation Performance](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/ImprovingAnimationPerformance/ImprovingAnimationPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH9-SW1) we find:

> **Use Asynchronous Layer Rendering As Needed**
>
> Any drawing that you do in your delegate’s `drawLayer:inContext:` method or your view’s `drawRect:` method normally occurs synchronously on your app’s main thread. In some situations, though, drawing your content synchronously might not offer the best performance. If you notice that your animations are not performing well, you might try enabling the `drawsAsynchronously` property on your layer to move those operations to a background thread. If you do so, make sure your drawing code is thread safe. And as always, you should always measure the performance of drawing asynchronously before putting it into your production code.

Important to note -- the docs are talking (mainly) about *animation* performance... not "single-rendering" tasks.

---

From some testing...

- It appears the layer **must be in the view hierarchy**. It doesn't have to actually be *visible* on the screen, but it cannot be a "stand-alone" layer.
- Many (such as 10,000) *simple paths* will take **longer** to render with `.drawsAsynchronously = true`
- Few (such as 20) *very complex paths* will take **longer** to render with `.drawsAsynchronously = false`
- As with almost everything, the *first time* we make use of a subsystem incurs overhead... so when trying to do something like measure render duration, we want to run it a couple times before we start timing it.

---

So, let's look at some actual example code that will demonstrate the difference. Too much to try and detail here, but the in-line comments should make it clear what's going on:

---

**custom `CALayer` subclass**:

```
class MyCustomDrawLayer: CALayer {
    
    // a property so the caller can read the last draw() duration
    var lastRenderDuration: Double = -1
    
    var pths: [CGPath] = []
    
    var cgStrokeColors: [CGColor] = []
    var cgFillColors: [CGColor] = []
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        let lineColors: [UIColor] = [
            .red, .systemGreen, .blue
        ]
        let fillColors: [UIColor] = [
            .yellow, .green, .cyan
        ]
        cgStrokeColors = lineColors.map({$0.cgColor})
        cgFillColors = fillColors.map({$0.cgColor})
    }
    
    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        super.draw(in: ctx)
        guard pths.count > 0 else { return }
        
        let drawStart = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        
        // cycle through 3 stroke/fill color sets as we draw the paths
        for (i, pth) in pths.enumerated() {
            ctx.setStrokeColor(cgStrokeColors[i % cgStrokeColors.count])
            ctx.setFillColor(cgFillColors[i % cgFillColors.count])
            ctx.addPath(pth)
            ctx.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
        }
        
        let drawEnd = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        lastRenderDuration = drawEnd - drawStart
    }
    
}
```

---

**"Swift Bird" path**:

```
class SwiftyBird: NSObject {
    func path(inRect: CGRect) -> UIBezierPath {
        let thisShape = UIBezierPath()
        
        thisShape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.31, y: 0.94))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.00, y: 0.64), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.18, y: 0.87), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.07, y: 0.76))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.12, y: 0.72), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.03, y: 0.67), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.07, y: 0.70))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.57, y: 0.72), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.28, y: 0.81), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.45, y: 0.80))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.57, y: 0.72), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.57, y: 0.72), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.57, y: 0.72))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.15, y: 0.23), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.40, y: 0.57), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.26, y: 0.39))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.10, y: 0.15), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.13, y: 0.21), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.11, y: 0.18))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.50, y: 0.49), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.22, y: 0.28), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.43, y: 0.44))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.22, y: 0.09), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.35, y: 0.31), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.21, y: 0.08))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.69, y: 0.52), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.46, y: 0.37), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.69, y: 0.52))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.71, y: 0.54), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.70, y: 0.53), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.70, y: 0.53))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.61, y: 0.00), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.77, y: 0.35), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.71, y: 0.15))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.92, y: 0.68), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.84, y: 0.15), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.98, y: 0.44))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.92, y: 0.70), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.92, y: 0.69), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.92, y: 0.70))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.92, y: 0.70), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.92, y: 0.70), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.92, y: 0.70))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.99, y: 1.00), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 1.00, y: 0.86), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 1.00, y: 1.00))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.93), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.92, y: 0.86), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.81, y: 0.90))
        thisShape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.31, y: 0.94), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.64, y: 1.01), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.47, y: 1.00))
        thisShape.close()
        
        let tr = CGAffineTransform(translationX: inRect.minX, y: inRect.minY)
            .scaledBy(x: inRect.width, y: inRect.height)
        thisShape.apply(tr)
        
        return thisShape
    }
}
```

Looks like this if `inRect` is (roughly) 200x200:

[image]

---

**Test View Controller class**:

```
class MyDrawAsyncTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let customLayer = MyCustomDrawLayer()

    var manySimplePaths: [CGPath] = []
    var fewComplexPaths: [CGMutablePath] = []
    
    var bUseManyPaths: Bool = true
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        // generate a 64x64 "grid" of 16x16 paths
        //  (fills the 1024x1024 size)
        let v: CGFloat = 16.0
        var r: CGRect = .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: v, height: v)
        for col in 0..<64 {
            for row in 0..<64 {
                r.origin = .init(x: CGFloat(col) * v, y: CGFloat(row) * v)
                manySimplePaths.append(SwiftyBird().path(inRect: r).cgPath)
            }
        }
        
        // manySimplePaths has 4096 paths
        
        fewComplexPaths = [
            CGMutablePath(),
            CGMutablePath(),
            CGMutablePath(),
        ]

        for (j, pth) in manySimplePaths.enumerated() {
            fewComplexPaths[j % fewComplexPaths.count].addPath(pth)
        }
        
        // fewComplexPaths produces the same output,
        //  but uses only 3 paths:
        //      [0] has 1366 subpaths
        //      [1] has 1365 subpaths
        //      [2] has 1365 subpaths

        customLayer.pths = manySimplePaths
        
        // the custom layer MUST be in the view hierarchy,
        //  but it doesn't have to be visible
        // so we'll add it as a sublayer but position it "out-of-frame"
        let sz: CGSize = .init(width: 1024.0, height: 1024.0)
        customLayer.frame = .init(x: -(sz.width + 10.0), y: -(sz.height + 10.0), width: sz.width, height: sz.height)
        view.layer.addSublayer(customLayer)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        // let's call the test/render func every second
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            self.testMe()
        })
    }
    
    // tap anywhere to toggle between manySimplePaths and fewComplexPaths
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        bUseManyPaths.toggle()
        customLayer.pths = bUseManyPaths ? manySimplePaths : fewComplexPaths
        print("\nSwitched to:", bUseManyPaths ? "manySimplePaths" : "fewComplexPaths", "\n")
    }
    
    var iCount: Int = 0
    
    func testMe() {
        
        let f = customLayer.frame
        
        // toggle .drawsAsynchronously each time through
        customLayer.drawsAsynchronously.toggle()
        
        let genImageStart = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(f.size)
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { fatalError("Could not get Context!!!") }
        
        let renderStart = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        
        // we want .render(in:) to trigger a call to draw(in:) in custom layer
        customLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
        
        // render the layer
        customLayer.render(in: ctx)
        
        let renderEnd = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        let genImageEnd = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        
        if iCount == 0 {
            print("\nWe're ignoring the first few timing values, so we're not measuring overhead...")
        }

        iCount += 1
        if iCount < 4 {
            print(iCount)
            return
        }
        var s: String = "async: \(customLayer.drawsAsynchronously)"
        s += customLayer.drawsAsynchronously ? "\t\t" : "\t"
        s += "Draw Time: "
        s += String(format: "%0.10f", customLayer.lastRenderDuration)
        s += "\t\t"
        s += "Render Time: "
        s += String(format: "%0.10f", renderEnd - renderStart)
        s += "\t\t"
        s += "Gen Image Time: "
        s += String(format: "%0.10f", genImageEnd - genImageStart)
        print(s)
        
    }

}
```

When running, we don't see anything on the screen (just yellow background so we know the app is "live").

It starts a timer, rendering a 1024x1024 image every second, alternating between `.drawsAsynchronously` true/false, and prints timing stats to the debug console.

Tapping anywhere toggles between rendering `manySimplePaths` or `fewComplexPaths` -- both produce the exact same output image.

You should see something similar to this in the debug console:

```
2024-01-17 13:00:38.706243-0500 MyProj[66254:6949370] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2024-01-17 13:00:38.708287-0500 MyProj[66254:6949370] Metal API Validation Enabled

We're ignoring the first few timing values, so we're not measuring overhead...
1
2
3
async: false    Draw Time: 0.0868519545     Render Time: 0.0882049799       Gen Image Time: 0.0901809931
async: true     Draw Time: 0.0249859095     Render Time: 0.1147090197       Gen Image Time: 0.1166020632
async: false    Draw Time: 0.0890671015     Render Time: 0.0899358988       Gen Image Time: 0.0919650793
async: true     Draw Time: 0.0232139826     Render Time: 0.1093589067       Gen Image Time: 0.1112560034

Switched to: fewComplexPaths 

async: false    Draw Time: 0.1343829632     Render Time: 0.1352089643       Gen Image Time: 0.1371099949
async: true     Draw Time: 0.0092250109     Render Time: 0.0681159496       Gen Image Time: 0.0701240301
async: false    Draw Time: 0.1334309578     Render Time: 0.1342890263       Gen Image Time: 0.1361669302
async: true     Draw Time: 0.0110900402     Render Time: 0.0679899454       Gen Image Time: 0.0699119568
```

---

The rendered 1024x1024 image should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer - I should have looked at `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` scale. So drawing is indeed faster with `drawsAsynchronously` enabled, but oddly rendering it to an image is slower. In fact, on my M1 iPad Pro, a lot slower. With async false, image gen is 0.096 and with it true it is 0.176 - nearly twice as slow.