# image coming blurred and screwed after applying rotation on image view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, transform, cgaffinetransform, image-rotation

I am stuck with a strange problem that,
I have a image view which has to shown at some angle approx 5 degree.For that I rotate my `UIImageView` to 5 degree but the image in `UIImageView` not coming proper as it was before transformation.

For more understanding see images

[image: image before rotation]
 [image: image after rotation]

You can see the second image is looking like clipped from corners and looks some blur also.

My code for rotation:-

```
myimageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians(5));
```

Please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `CGContextRotateCTM(context, radians);` and  `[sourceImage drawInRect:rect];`?

Comment: Please elaborate , how to use this hint.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are several solutions located in this similar SO Q&A:
[Any quick and dirty anti-aliasing techniques for a rotated UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136110/any-quick-and-dirty-anti-aliasing-techniques-for-a-rotated-uiimageview)

If it is, in fact, just the edges that are jagged, try adding a 1px transparent border around in image content (this is a suggestion in the above link).