# UIImageView image blur after rotate it

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I rotate a `UIImageView` using the following code:

```
[imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.10)];
```

but it looks blurry after the rotation, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999483/image-coming-blurred-and-screwed-after-applying-rotation-on-image-view).

What's the problem?

Comment: But the link you gave contains also the solution....

Comment: i use that link solution still it blurry

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the resulting frame isn't aligned on an even integer. When you are drawing on a half-pixel boundary, some of the drawing routines are going to make things look blurry.
If you see any non-integer values, use one of the `floor()` functions to modify the resulting frame in order to snap it to a boundary.