# Titanium create2DMatrix ugly transformation result

Tags: ios, titanium, transformation, titanium-mobile

Hi I quite finished my third app with Titanium. This time is not for a customer but for my self, and I did a very smart ux and ui. I loved titanium but I met only a big limit thet I wish you can help me to solve. I used code like this

```
 myPicImageView.transform = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate(-3);
```

To rotate some pic, but I have a very ugly result with corner like little stairs (sorry for my english but I can't explain better) is like low low low resolution when I rotate something. There's a way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rotating any view a non-multiple of pi / 2 while cause jagged edges as UIKit does not anti alias views when rendering. for images there is a simple solution, use an image with a single pixel width of transparency around the edge, then the rotated image view will have anti aliased edges.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136110/any-quick-and-dirty-anti-aliasing-techniques-for-a-rotated-uiimageview) post for more details.